# How to use x-init to set 'selected' attribute of dropdown option using AlpineJS

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have a form which is submitted using AlpineJS.

Using `x-init` I want to default the drop down to a specific country using a two letter string read from a cookie.

How can I use the 2 leter code I get in `initForm()` to set the `selected` attribute of the dropdown?

```html
<div x-data="marketingForm()" x-init="initForm()">
  <form id="formID-Contact" name="Contact" data-pageurl="http://localhost:8080/form-test/" class="">
    <div>
      <label for="country" >Country / Region</label>
      <select id="country" name="country" autocomplete="country">
        <option value='GB'>United Kingdom</option>
        <option value='US'>United States</option>
        <option value='CA'>Canada</option>
        <option value='MX'>Mexico</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <a>
      <button @click.prevent=submitMarketingForm() id='formSubmitButton'>submit</button>
    </a>
  </form>
</div>
```

And the JS

```js
window.marketingForm = () => {
  return {
    detectedCountry: '',
    initForm() {
      let country = getCountry() // function that reads a cookie and returns 2 letter code eg. UK. 
      this.detectedCountry = country // how do I use this to set selected attribute of relevant option
      
    },
    submitMarketingForm(formID) {
      // Do the form submitting stuff
    }
  }
}
```

So assuming `detectedCountry` is set to UK I want to end up with:

```html
<select id="country" name="country" autocomplete="country">
  <option selected value='GB'>United Kingdom</option>
  <option value='US'>United States</option>
  <option value='CA'>Canada</option>
  <option value='MX'>Mexico</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 8):

Just bind the selected attribute if the country's key is equal to the detectedCountry. I'd suggest storing the countries in your data object.

```
<div x-data="marketingForm()" x-init="initForm()">
  <form id="formID-Contact" name="Contact" data-pageurl="http://localhost:8080/form-test/" class="">
    <div>
      <label for="country" >Country / Region</label>
      <select id="country" name="country" autocomplete="country">
        <template x-for="country in countries">
          <option 
            :value='country.key'
            :selected="country.key === detectedCountry"
            x-text="country.name"
          >
          </option>
        </template>
      </select>
    </div>
    <a>
      <button @click.prevent=submitMarketingForm() id='formSubmitButton'>submit</button>
    </a>
  </form>
</div>


<script>
const marketingForm = () => {
  return {
    countries: [
      { key: 'GB', name: 'United Kingdom' },
      { key: 'US', name: 'United States' },
      { key: 'CA', name: 'Canada' },
      { key: 'MX', name: 'Mexico' },
    ],
    detectedCountry: '',
    initForm() {
      let country = 'GB' // function that reads a cookie and returns 2 letter code eg. UK. 
      this.detectedCountry = country // how do I use this to set selected attribute of relevant option
      
    },
    submitMarketingForm(formID) {
      // Do the form submitting stuff
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @dwkns if that helped solving your problem, it'd be nice if you could upvote my answer

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to literally set the `select` attribute, follow @NICO's answer. If, however, your goal is to just set the value of the select, you can make your life much easier. There's 2 options:

**Option 1:** Add an [`x-ref`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/ref) to the select:

`<select x-ref="country-select">`

Then, within your Alpine function, you can simply do the following:

`this.$refs['country-select'].value = country;`

This will set the value of the select to your country, and this will update your select accordingly.

**Option 2:** Use [`x-model`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/model):

`<select x-model="detectedCountry">`

This does the same as above, except you'll let Alpine do the magic for you. You won't have to do anything else.